# use case condition when inserting

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Here is some SQL which is working fine inside and SP (SQL Server 2000)

```
Insert into #sysAccrual
Select 'R', Cast(S.ServicePurchaseLineID as varchar),
    - S.Amount, dateadd(mm, 1, S.Date), null, L.LicenceTypeID, null,
    L.LicenceID, L.LicenceNumber
from sysMYOB_SP S inner join Licence L ON S.LicenceID = L.LicenceID 
        and S.PaymentReasonID = 2 
        and S.Accrued = 0
        and S.Deducted = 1
        and datediff(yy, S.Date, @AccrualMonth) = 0
        and datediff(mm, S.Date, @AccrualMonth) = 0
```

I would like to place a condition around this part 'dateadd(mm, 1, S.Date)'  Should  e able to do this:

```
Insert into #sysAccrual
Select 'R', Cast(S.ServicePurchaseLineID as varchar), - S.Amount, 
       case when 
       dateDiff(d, S.Date , LCS.statusDateTo) > 31 THEN 
     dateadd(mm, 1, S.Date), 
   ELSE 
         S.Date, 
   END 
       null, L.LicenceTypeID, null,
       L.LicenceID, L.LicenceNumber
from sysMYOB_SP S inner join Licence L ON S.LicenceID = L.LicenceID 
              inner join licCurrentStatus LCS ON L.LicenceID = LCS.LicenceID 
        and S.PaymentReasonID = 2 
        and S.Accrued = 0
        and S.Deducted = 1
        and datediff(yy, S.Date, @AccrualMonth) = 0
        and datediff(mm, S.Date, @AccrualMonth) = 0
```

@ghost my questions is can I do this part of the second query:

```
 case when 
 dateDiff(d, S.Date , LCS.statusDateTo) > 31 THEN 
    dateadd(mm, 1, S.Date), 
 ELSE 
    S.Date, 
 END
```

I am unsure if a case ca be used inside an insert like I have done.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: You forgot a comma after `END` if that's your actual code

Comment: And remove commas in `THEN` and `ELSE` after ` dateadd(mm, 1, S.Date)` and `S.Date` respectively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commas for your CASE statement were incorrect

Instead of

```
case when 
   dateDiff(d, S.Date , LCS.statusDateTo) > 31 THEN 
 dateadd(mm, 1, S.Date), 
ELSE 
     S.Date, 
END
```

you should have

```
case when 
 dateDiff(d, S.Date , LCS.statusDateTo) > 31 THEN 
 dateadd(mm, 1, S.Date)
ELSE 
 S.Date
END,
```

Comment: OK thank you.  So after moving the commers I should be able to use a case inside an INSERT like this?